# how to filter an object with RegExp and return a new object

Tags: javascript

I have an object:

```
object1 = {
dEabc: 1,
dEasdf: 2,
dEjfhs: 5,
bhsn: 7,
oki: 9
}
```

My goal is to get a new object which contains only the keys with "dE", that means:

```
object1 = {
dEabc: 1,
dEasdf: 2,
dEjfhs: 5,
}
```

is the object that I expected.

What I have tried is, 
firstly I got all key from this object with

```
Object.keys(object);
```

and then I used a RegExp to check if properties in the object with relevant keys.
if not I use

```
delete object[key];
```

Any solutions?

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Perhaps a `Map` would be a better fit here.

Comment: ... *"and what exactly is the problem with it?"* Give a [mre], not just a description.

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `Object.entries()` to deconstruct the object, `filter()` it, and reconstruct it with `Object.fromEntries()`:

```js
const o = {
  dEabc: 1,
  dEasdf: 2,
  dEjfhs: 5,
  bhsn: 7,
  oki: 9
};

const result = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(o).filter(([k]) => k.includes('dE')));

console.log(result);
```

No need for a regex for an expression this simple.

Comment: I was literally just thinking this when your answer popped up.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var obj= {
dEabc: 1,
dEasdf: 2,
dEjfhs: 5,
bhsn: 7,
oki: 9
}
let aa = Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc,ele)=>{return (ele.indexOf('dE') != -1) ? {...acc,...{[ele]:obj[ele]}} : acc},{});
console.log(aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

With `reduce`, it can be done this way:

```js
object1 = {
dEabc: 1,
dEasdf: 2,
dEjfhs: 5,
bhsn: 7,
oki: 9
}

let finalObj = Object.keys(object1).filter(i=>i.includes('dE')).reduce((obj, curr)=>{
     return {...obj, ...{[curr]: object1[curr]}};
},{});
console.log(finalObj);
```